# Finding Cheapest Combination of Tickets

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming

I'm writing a web application to help commuters determine the cheapest combination of tickets to purchase for their daily commute based on how many trips they take in a month.

I've done a bunch of reading on this, but I'm still not quite sure how I would implement this. I think it could be similar to [the knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) or some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814678/how-to-determine-cheapest-commute-ticket-combination) questions on here, but I still find the answers quite confusing.

---

There are three ticket types:

**Single Trip**: $6.50

**10 Trips**: $49.80

**Monthly Pass**: $149.40

---

I want to be able to compute the *combination* of tickets that has the lowest total price which covers a given number of monthly trips for a commuter.

---

Example:

*For 12 trips in a month, the cheapest combination is one 10 Trip pass and two Single passes for a total of $62.80.*

---

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction (with pseudocode or otherwise) on how I would implement this? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: If you write that down, this is not much more than a few if-else's in a loop and simple divide/remainder arithmetic (loop can obviously be skipped if the above is the exact task as there is an upper-limit and the size of potential cases is small). No need to use heavy-tools (e.g. knapsack-solvers). This might be due to your example, because this one allows so many reductions which you can do without a PC (10 trips dominating single-trip for some n >= N; 10T == MP in terms of cost-per-trip and so on). So: write it down, analyze. **Then** come back and ask a specific question if it's not working

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

As [sascha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2320035/sascha) suggested in their comment, I was actually able to implement this fairly simply.

With *n* as the total number of trips:

- The number of ten trip tickets to use is *(n % 10)*
- The number of single tickets to use is *(n / 10)* using integer division
- If the total cost of these tickets is greater than the cost of a monthly ticket, use a monthly ticket.

## The Code

```js
for (i = 0; i < Math.floor(totalNumTrips / 10); i++) {
    ticketsToBuy.push(TicketType.TenTrip);
    cost += tenTripPrice;
}

for (i = 0; i < totalNumTrips % 10; i++) {
    ticketsToBuy.push(TicketType.Single);
    cost += singlePrice;
}

if (monthlyPrice < cost) {
    return {
        tickets: [TicketType.Monthly],
        cost: monthlyPrice,
    };
}
return {
    tickets: ticketsToBuy,
    cost: cost,
};
```

Hopefully this is helpful to someone!